# What's the font on the Input Sources icons?

Tags: keyboard, font, input-source

I want to create a Keylayout with a custom icon using Ukelele. What´s the font on the defaults icons? Also, is there are resource to edit this icon easily without having to recreate it completely?

[image: Icon for Spanish keyboard layout]

Comment: Try this group   https://groups.google.com/g/ukelele-users?pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is San Francisco, the default system font on Macs. An official free download is available here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

The weight is probably Semibold.

Answer (score 0):

I used this `imagemagic`script to generate `icns` on `macOS`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the output PNG file
output_base_name="icon"
output_icon="${output_base_name}_64x64.png"

# Image size and padding values
image_width=64
image_height=64
horizontal_padding=1
vertical_padding=1
corner_radius=4

# Text settings
text="BŁ"
text_vertical_padding=12
font_size=$((image_height - 2 * vertical_padding - 2 * text_vertical_padding))  # Adjust the font size based on your preference

# Create a transparent background
convert -size ${image_width}x${image_height} xc:none -alpha transparent background.png

# Calculate coordinates for rounded rectangle
end_x=$((image_width - horizontal_padding))
end_y=$((image_height - vertical_padding))

# Draw a rounded-corner white rectangle with padding
convert background.png -fill white -draw "roundrectangle ${horizontal_padding},${vertical_padding} ${end_x},${end_y} ${corner_radius},${corner_radius}" rectangle.png

# Add text in the middle of the rectangle
convert background.png -background none -fill black -gravity center -font '.SF-Compact-Semibold-G2' -pointsize ${font_size} -annotate +2+0 "${text}" text.png

# Composite the text on the rounded rectangle
composite -gravity center -compose difference rectangle.png text.png "$output_icon"

# Cleanup temporary files
rm background.png rectangle.png text.png

output_icon_32="${output_base_name}_32x32.png"
convert "$output_icon" -resize 32x32 "$output_icon_32"

iconset_dir="Belarusian_Latin.iconset"
mkdir "$iconset_dir"
cp "$output_icon" "$output_icon_32" "$iconset_dir/"

iconutil -c icns "$iconset_dir" -o 'Belarusian (Latin).icns' 
rm -rf ${output_base_name}_*.png "$iconset_dir"
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to create rectangle shape the same size as a system one